# Create Sub Menu in android

Tags: android

I want to create a **Sub Menu** in existing **Menu Item** in **Android**.

How I can achieve it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's as simple as placing a `menu` inside an `item`.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/file"
          android:icon="@drawable/file"
          android:title="@string/file" >
        <!-- "file" submenu -->
        <menu>
            <item android:id="@+id/create_new"
                  android:title="@string/create_new" />
            <item android:id="@+id/open"
                  android:title="@string/open" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

From [Creating Menus | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#submenu)

Answer (score -1):

Try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#submenu) first.